# How do I decrypt the following hash from a sqlmap output i have try with to many ways but not working

Tags: hash, hashcode

These are outputs for data in column Password from a table.

34857ee0ffba0f1a0f63b09ae823f891

How do I decrypt this given that I've ran it through different hash decrypting programs and keep getting an error? What kind of hash is this? (MD5, etc...)?

I've used python /usr/bin/findmyhash and different online hash decrypting sites. I tried hashcat but totally unfamiliar with it and would need to study it.

Comment: You can't decrypt a hash. Hashes are hashed not encrypted. The whole point of hashing is that it isn't reversible.

Comment: If you're trying to verify that a user entered the correct password, you don't do that by "decrypting" the hash and comparing it to what the user typed. Instead, you hash what the user typed and then compare *that* hash to the one you have stored in the database.

Comment: @AlexHowansky im not the Admin Im Just Trying To Do SQL Injection

Comment: What does reversing a hash have to do with SQL injection?

Comment: @AlexHowansky To Connect Like a Admin

Comment: So... you want us to help you hack this site?